# Android application focus

Tags: android, focus

I have a need to force my application to the front under special circumstances. I know its against the good coding philosophy but I am working on a turnkey solution where I control the complete device. The app is used internally as a business tool and supplied to the users on a stripped down device. I have searched but cannot see a way but know that it can be done as in the Application Protection app. This can react to the launching of an application and kill it / allow it by entering a password.

Answer (score 0):

Your background process (Service) just needs to transmit the intent required to launch the activity. See [Context.startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)